# I have Created Custom Accordion in React.js in that my toggle is working but it open all items

Tags: html, reactjs, api, axios

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Faq = () => {
  const [faq, setFaq] = useState([]);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const fetchFaqs = async () => {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost/faq/allFaq`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );
      setFaq(res.data.proData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFaqs();
  });
 if(faq.length > 0)
 {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>

        <Navbar />
        <div className="FaqHeader">
          <div className="bhtext pt-3">
            <h1 className="pb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
            <p className="hometext px-3">
              It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
              making it over 2000 years <br /> old. Richard McClintock
            </p>
            <p className="addressbar pb-3 mb-0">
              Home <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i> <span>Faq</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container-fluid faqmain">
          <div className="faqacc">
                <div className="pt-3">
                  <div className="faqTitle">
                    <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
                  </div>
                    {faq.map((faqe, index) => {
                      return (
                        <div className="faqAccordion">
                          <div className="accordion-item my-3">
                            <div className="accordion-title" onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>
                              <div className="me-2 plus">{isActive ? "-" : "+"}</div>
                                <div>{faqe.title}</div>
                              </div>
                              {isActive && (<div className="accordion-content ps-5">{faqe.description}</div>)}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
};
export default Faq;
```

I have Created Custom Accordion and Fetch an api of Faq in React.js in that my toggle is working fine but it open all items Here in This Code I want to toggle open and close a Single Faq Accordion item but it opens all the accordion items To toggle only the selected accordion item So anybody help me on this Code.

Comment: You are trying to use a single boolean (isActive) to store the state of all items, which is obviously not possible. You could convert your isActive variable to an array, but I would personally define a new component for a single FAQ item. This new component could store its own open/close state as a boolean

Answer (score 0):

To make only one accordion open at a time, you need to keep track of the active accordion's index instead of using a single state variable to control all of them. You can achieve this by modifying the isActive state to be an array of booleans, where each boolean value corresponds to an accordion's active state.

```
...
  const [faq, setFaq] = useState([]);
  const [activeIndices, setActiveIndices] = useState([]);
  
  const fetchFaqs = async () => {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost/faq/allFaq`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      );
      setFaq(res.data.proData);
      setActiveIndices(Array(res.data.proData.length).fill(false));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFaqs();
  }, []);

  const toggleAccordion = (index) => {
    setActiveIndices((prev) =>
      prev.map((active, i) => (i === index ? !active : false))
    );
  };
...
```